# Can't clear localstorage using localstorage.clear();

Tags: javascript, jquery, axios, local-storage

Need some help, i try to clear local storage using localStorage.clear() and it doesn't work. Here's how i store the localstorage:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event)
    {
        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

            localStorage.setItem("first_name", $('#first_name').val());
            localStorage.setItem("middle_name", $('#middle_name').val());
            localStorage.setItem("last_name", $('#last_name').val());
            localStorage.setItem("address", $('#address').val());

        } else {

            alert('No Web Storage support')

        }
};
```

here's how i call the localstorage:

```
window.onload = function() {
        let first_name = localStorage.getItem("first_name");
        if (first_name !== null) $('#first_name').val(first_name);
        let middle_name = localStorage.getItem("middle_name");
        if (middle_name !== null) $('#middle_name').val(middle_name);
        let last_name = localStorage.getItem("last_name");
        if (last_name !== null) $('#last_name').val(last_name);
        let address = localStorage.getItem("address");
    }
```

Here's the way i clear my local storage:

```
axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: '/applicant-managements/store',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
                data: data,
            }).then(function (response) {

                if (response.data.type === 'success'){

                   localStorage.clear();

                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: "success",
                        title: response.data.text,
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        timer: 2000
                    }).then(function(){

                        window.location.href = "/admin/applicant-managements";

                    })

                }else{

                    Swal.fire(
                        "Failed!",
                        response.data.text,
                        "error"
                    )
                }

            }).catch(function (error) {
                Swal.fire("Error!", "Internal error, please refresh the page if this error persist please contact " +
                    "your administrator!", "error");
            })

        })
```

It still can't clear the localstorage data although respon.data.type is success. I try using window.localStorage.clear(); but it doesn't work either. Is it have something to do with Axios?

Comment: Can you show an example of logging out `localStorage` before and after you call `localStorage.clear()`

Comment: @aphextwix ok please wait, i will update my question with how i call and set the localstorage.

Comment: Can you add the exact content of `response.data`?

Comment: Change `response.data.type === 'success'` to `response.data.type == 'success'` and try. Use console to log `data` and check spelling and type of `success` keyword.

Comment: @AsfanShaikh no that's not the problem since  Swal.fire work fine. plus i tested before by adding console log after response.data.type === 'success' and it's work just fine. so that's not the problem.

Comment: @Ying - You're clearing localStorage with `localStorage.clear()` in the success and then you're setting `window.location.href` which will trigger your `onbeforeunload` handler. Would that explain why you think it isn't clearing?

Comment: @aphextwix ah i see your point, so do you have a solution about how i can redirect without triggering that onbeforeunload? or is it any better method than using onbeforeunload?

Comment: @Ying you can reset all fields value while changing URL.

Comment: @AsfanShaikh when i think about it i have no problem when i'm using jquery ajax. and beside i put localStorage.clear(); before i do redirect. so i think it suppose clear the storage already before redirect, no?

Comment: @Ying - Well do you need the `onbeforeunload` handler? I'm sorry, it's hard to why you're clearing storage and then setting it again? Could you provide more of an explanation please.

Comment: @Ying try `window.onkeyup` instead of `window.onbeforeunload`

Comment: @aphextwix i clear the storage if the form is successfully submited. here's the complete source code if you want to take a look: https://pastebin.com/C3mDUkGp

Comment: @AsfanShaikh wait i will give it try.

Comment: @AsfanShaikh - Why `onkeyup`? That's completely different functionality to `onbeforeunload`. 

@Ying I would recommend removing the `onbeforeunload` and only setting the items in localStorage when needed rather than on every page redirect/refresh.

Comment: @AsfanShaikh window.onkeyup seems it work only on input but not with the select menu.

Comment: @aphextwix but that was work to clear after success, so you have better idea?

Comment: @Ying You can also clear localStorage in your code before closing `window.onload`

Comment: @AsfanShaikh if i do that if the form is failed to submit then data will not saved. The purpose i do this script is so when user submit their data but the form is error they can clear the data without have to retype the data again.

Comment: I mean they can refresh the form without having to type again.

Comment: @Ying then put it after `window.location.href = "/admin/applicant-managements";`

Comment: @AsfanShaikh how can it executed after the page already redirected?

Comment: @Ying use `document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].onsubmit` instead of 'window.onbeforeunload` you can change target form element using particular `id` or `class`. Fingers crossed. I wish this will work :)

Comment: @AsfanShaikh that not what i want. Sometime user can submit but there's server error. so if i do what u suggest the form input will disappear when there's error on the server.